# How to implement WPF Ribbon Contextual Tabs MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm developing MVVM application using WPF Ribbon control from Office UI licensing site as main menu. And I can not bind or somehow inject contextual tabs into my ribbon control. I do not want to store all contextual tabs markup and command bindings in my main view, I want to use this tabs depending on view selected and store this tabs maybe in same view or some special view with only this type of tabs. Is it possible?

Comment: You need some sort of ViewModelTemplate selector. Where the data template will be selected by the string name of the template that you might specify in each view model. Sorry if my answer is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to write `Style`s or even `ControlTemplate`s for the various `RibbonTab`s in your App.config, avoiding the need to put that markup in the `MainWindow`. Then simply add *all* the `RibbonTab`s into the `Ribbon` in `MainWindow.xaml` and set the `Visibility` properties of each by binding to the main view model. You could use a load of `bool` properties in the main view model with a simple `bool` to `Visibility` converter.

Comment: I programmed it out in pure MVVM. Check this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2OckuDTLwnZ86p50Keyh_67zz2eWwFC/view?usp=sharing